# javascript - Getting a JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

So I have a stock website that I want to be able to obtain the JSON information from either Google's API or Yahoo's API website. I am currently just testing so that is why I used a replacement function for my console log to print it onto a text box for my testing atm. I can not seem to get this to work correctly, I have looked on other pure JS script, but I am currently stump, I have read past posts, but they're very similar in answers, and I have tried implementing.

It works with a fully JSON string, with just {}, where I can just access the inner elements. However, even accessing it, what I believe to be the correct way, it does not seem to work. And I tried with other API with a different method and it worked fine.... Anyone can explain? And I also tried using $.getJSON

```
       $.get("http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=y&region=US&lang=en-US", function(data) {
             var dropDownHTML;
             var stock = data.ResultSet.Result;
             for (var i = 0, len = stock.length ;i<len;i++){
             dropDownHTML += '<option value="' + stock[i].symbol + '">' + stock[i].name + '</option>';
        }
        document.getElementById("options").innerHTML = dropDownHTML;
          });
          </script>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that the website you are scraping from has specifically blocked HTTP requests. You'll need to connect with HTTPS instead:

```
https://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json
```

Also, you're returning a large array of objects from your scrape -- you'd need to loop through, and log the contents of each object individually:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

I've created a Fiddle showing a working scrape [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/ut63wb53/1/).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work. Or at least display on my div? I updated to basically what you gave me.

Comment: It's working in the fiddle -- it's probably because you include jQuery **after** you try to use it in your above example. Try shifting your jQuery reference to above it, and see if that fixes it. Also see if there are any error messages in your Developer Tools (F12) :)

Comment: Damn, you gotta be kidding me. That was the problem, my script was declared below it x.x. You're the MVP.

Comment: Quick question, regarding the google API, there is a weird // on the JSON array, is there a way I can take the data as a string and splice it?

Comment: You sure can, just use `str.slice()` -- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp. I can't see any slashes in the JSON on the fiddle, but you should be able to parse it however you'd like with a little manipulation :)

Comment: Hmm, it does not seem to work Google's API nor Yahoo's API? Nothing is being displayed

Comment: The JSON comes through correctly on the fiddle. Remember to check your error logs, and debug. I don't see any slashes, nor do I know how you're using `str.slice()` to remove them. In your updated example, you **do** need `data`, as **data** is whatever is returned from the `getJSON` call! There's no point making the call if you don't use the response ;) You may need to do a bit of reading up, or you may need to open another question, but for now, the solution I provided is perfectly valid.